# Train a model with probability response (or number of successes/failures) rather than binary outputs

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-modeling

I have aggregated data impressions and clicks by set of features.
And would like to use scikit-learn to estimate probability to click (CTR).
I.e. the response variable is the number of clicks divided by the number of impressions (#clicks/#impressions).

How I can **train** a model with a probability response (CTR)  (or number of clicks/impressions) rather than a binary output ?

Note : similar to the R glm with binomial family ( http://data.princeton.edu/R/glms.html )

Data for example :

[image: Data for example]

Thanks,
Boris

Comment: you basically just want a classifier that has a probabilistic interpretation. Try logistic regression, see the examples here http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/classification/plot_classification_probability.html#example-classification-plot-classification-probability-py

Comment: In this example Logistic regression classifier has multiclass respond variable. how can I use probability as a respond and not a class. ? or maybe the question how I can tell the logistic take the two columns (#clicks , #impressions) and interpret them as probability to click .

Answer (score 0):

Use `predict_proba` instead of `predict` to get the probability instead of just the binary output. Details can be found [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/skflow/blob/master/skflow/estimators/base.py#L312).

See discussion on Github [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/skflow/issues/136).

Comment: Thanks ! I meant how to input aggregated data into the logistic regression.Instead of '1' for success and '0' for failure. input as the Y attribute total number of successes and failures per aggregation level.